# A problem related to Sobolev space

Tags: partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

This problem basically arises when I read Gilbarg and trudinger’s PDE books theorem 8.26. To avoid too many notations, I rewrite the problem as follows:

Given an open bounded and connected subset $\Omega\subset R^n$, let $u\in W^{1,2}(\Omega)$, now if the following holds:
$$
M:=\sup_{\partial \Omega\cap B_{2R}}u^+, \text{ here } B_{2R}\text{ is any ball in }R^n, \ u_M^+= \sup{u,M}\text{ if }x\in \Omega;
u_M^+=M, \text{ if }x \notin \Omega.
$$
And
$$
\bar{u}=u_M^++k,\ v=\eta^\beta(\bar{u}^\beta-(M+k)^\beta),\beta>0,k \text{ is some positive constant, } \eta \in C^1_0(B_{4R})
$$
We further have
$$
\sup_{\partial \Omega} u=\inf _{\partial \Omega}\{k|(u-k)^+\in W_0^{1,2}(\Omega)\}
$$

Now my question is : if $\bar{u}$ is bounded, how can we show  $v\in W_0^{1,2}(B_{2R})$?
(it is natural for $ v \in W_0^{1,2}(\Omega\cap B_{2R})$.)
A picture shows the relationship between $\Omega$ and the ball.
[image]

Comment: You should use \text{ ... } to write text inside equations. But the best is to write several equations

Comment: Let me guess. $\Omega$ is likely needs to be Lipschitz to have good boundary. Maybe there is something about Calderon extension operator in the book.

Comment: @LL 3.14 thanks for the correction, it is my honor to get your help.

Comment: @dsh. The problem is this region’s boundary regularity is not so good.